# nativeDroid 2 left panel not working when I visit same page second time

Tags: cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile, sidebar, nativedroid

**nativeDroid2** left panel not working  when I visit same page second time.or When i go back in cordova app
It simply stays on overlay effect. I am using **jQuery Mobile** pages not normal pages.

Comment: I am sorry, but honestly it would be a lot more easier for SO people to help You, if You could provide the source code demonstrating this issue. Can You create a Fiddle or something similar with an example for this issue? A sentence like "panell not working" isn't a good hint for anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have put this it will work on you...

```
 <div data-role="panel" id="leftpaneltry" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
  <div class="ui-panel-inner">
      <div class='nd2-sidepanel-profile wow fadeInDown' style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 112, 229, 0.4), rgba(0, 112, 229, 0.76));">

          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-xs-4 center-xs'>
              <div class='box'>
                <img class="profile-thumbnail" src="img/avathar.jpg" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-8'>
              <div class='box profile-text' style="color: black">
                <strong style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="sprofilen"> </strong>
                <span class='subline' id="stype" style="font-size: 17px;"></span>
                  <a  onclick="stud()"  style="color: white" ><span>  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px;">create </i> 
                Update Profile &ensp;</span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
        <li><a  onclick="viewjob()" data-ajax='false'  data-icon="false">View Jobs</a></li>
          <li><a onclick="viewment()" data-ajax='false'   data-icon="false">View Mentors</a></li>


         <li><a onclick="traininglistvi()" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Browse Training Institutes</a></li>
          </ul>



          <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" data-iconpos="right">
          <h3>My Requests</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
            <li><a href="#studreqjob1" data-transition="flip" >Post a Job</a></li>
            <li><a href="#studreqproj" data-transition="flip">Post for Project Assistance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#studreqtrain"  data-transition="flip"  data-icon="false">Post for Training</a></li>
            <li><a  onclick="viewres()" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">View Reponses</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Job Requests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Project Assistance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Training Requests</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>


      <ul data-role="listview" >
          <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">My Connections</a></li>

        </ul>


        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" data-iconpos="right">
          <h3>My Preferences</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false'>Mentors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false'>Training Institutes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Change Password</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>




      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
          <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Contact Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pageone" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Logout</a></li>

        </ul>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewjob.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewmentor.js"> </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/other.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
  function suser1() {
      document.getElementById("sprofilen").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('first_name1')+" "+window.localStorage.getItem('last_name1');
  document.getElementById("stype").innerHTML= window.localStorage.getItem('user_type');

  }
</script>

      </div>
  </div>

after put this code in your 
     $('#leftpaneltry').enhanceWithin().panel();
```